# Microsoft visual studio 2012 Devenv not found?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, ide

I am facing a strange problem when trying to install Microsoft visual studio ultimate 2012
It breaks during installation saying

Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Devenv
  Élément introuvable(Element not found).

[image]

I googled it and i didn't find anything interressant or usefull.
Did anyone face this problem before?
If so is there a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do the windows updates and fix it. It worked on me.